# Unit Test Coverage; Graphical Display

Tags: continuous-integration, code-coverage, dotcover

I have been tasked with introducing automated unit test coverage reporting to our CI build environment (we use Hudson and MSBuild).  I have used dotCover to produce the coverage data across several projects within a build job, merge that data, produce a single HTML report and integrated that with the Hudson dashboard for that job using the HTML Publisher Hudson add-in.

So far so good.  But, what we ultimately want is a graphical display of unit test coverage metrics across the entire system code base (half a dozen build jobs, circa 50 projects) up on one of our team displays; a highly visible 'at a glance' test coverage status.  I can build this myself with an app that will merge the dotCover coverage reports for all builds, report to xml and build my own UI around that, but is there a product out there that does this already? We are not married to dotCover, that can change, and it's doesn't have to be free or open source either.

Answer (score 1):

We are using NCover to get the test coverage and a bunch of other code metrics(symbol coverage, branch coverage and cyclomatic complexity).

It is pretty good for highlighting the coverage, you can browse through the source code as part of the reports and see which lines are covered and which are not.

You can also exclude test categories or specific namespaces from your reports.

As far as I know it integrates with Hudson.

Comment: I have looked at NCover but (unless I missed something) it's the at-a-glance aggregated status display that is missing. That is the piece I'm really looking for before I set about building it myself.

Comment: You can use NCover to generate the pretty status reports once a build completed and then dotCover to get instant feedback on the tests that you are writing(and probably running in resharper). I think this is the best combination for commercial tools out there(for .net shops anyway). I have also tried opencover/partcover together with nCrunch, but although nCrunch was nice, but not as good as dotCover, I did not like opencover. Speaking of unit tests, you should have a look at this article posted by Martin Fowler yesterday: http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestCoverage.html

Comment: @lexalizer what did you not like about OpenCover - interested in feedback

Comment: @ShaunWilde The tool itself is great and I think you are doing a wonderful job maintaining this piece of software. When I tried the tool, I found that some statement coverage metrics provided by it were a bit different than what dotCover and NCover were saying. Furthermore, some large corporations don't really like taking risks with open source software unless there is no alternative. I would happily use OpenCover for my personal projects though. An up to date documentation would be great. Some detailed tutorials will attract more users to the project. Keep up the good work. Thumbs up.

Comment: @lexalizer thanks, I thought the latest Usage.pdf was quite detailed - ah well

Answer (score 1):

[OpenCover](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover) and [PartCover](https://github.com/sawilde/partcover.net4) are both open source code coverage tools that can be integrated into build automation systems.

With both you can use [ReportGenerator](http://reportgenerator.codeplex.com/) to display results; though PartCover does come with it's own viewer I prefer to use the ReportGenerator one myself as the HTML can be integrated quite nicely into a build status report.

You may also build your own reports using XSLT or such like as both tools have an XML output.

Answer (score 1):

Our [C# Test Coverage Tool](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/CSharpTestCoverage.html) tool can combine test coverage vectors for separate C# artifacts into a single overall view, out of the box.

In fact, [our family of test coverage tools](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage) will can combine results from multiple different languages (e.g., C#, VB.net, C++, Java, PHP, COBOL, ...) in the same way.

The tool(s) provide both visual view of the covered code, and reports of the coverage data including in an XML form.

Answer (score 0):

I like the treemap functionality from SonarQube a lot, but this only works for one 'project' in SonarQube, nevertheless, a great tool to look into.

Google for SonarQube and treemap for examples.